# Microphone not working on Centos 6.5

Tags: audio, hardware, centos

I have installed CentOS 6.5 on a Dell Insperion with an Intel chip. I first noticed that my microphone is not working on Skype on CentOS although it was working fine with Windows 7 on the same box. The speakers work fine on both operating systems. I did the following test.

```
arecord -vv -d 10 test.wav
aplay -vv test.wav
```

and did not get any sound played back. I went to System:Preferences:Sound to get the Sound Preferences dialog. I went to the Input tab and "Microphone" was selected as the connector. I turned the input volume up to maximum and spoke into the microphone but the "Input level" boxes all remained a light grey like it was disabled. The only option for "Choose a device for sound input" is "Internal Audio Analog Stereo".

Comment: CentOS 6.5 has a very outdated kernel which means the mic might not work because your kernel sound drivers don't talk to your hardware properly. I can't say for sure that's the case but it's very likely.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I now use CentOS 7.8 and have no problems with the microphone or speakers.  Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try install pavucontrol.

```
yum install pavucontrol
```

After installation, from menu open PulseAudio Volume Control

Here the input devices will be detected. The built-in volume control seem to face some problem. It worked for me.